# How to open Android Play Store settings page programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play-services

I want to open Play store Setting page.though I know how to open play store

```
final String appName = "";
        try {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id="+appName)));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+appName)));
    }
```

> but I want to open play store setting(to redirect user to auto update
>   option) page that look like this image

[image]

How to do this.Is there any intent for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that using this :

```
try {
      Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.android.finsky.activities.SettingsActivity");
      intent.setClassName("com.android.vending", "com.google.android.finsky.activities.SettingsActivity");
      startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use the App [Intent Intercept](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.ashtonbrsc.android.intentintercept&hl=de) to find the intent for the PlayStore Settings-Activity.

I guess you can just run the app to start tracking and then open PlayStore and go to settings. Intent Intercept should show you the called Intents.

Comment: I have installed that app but could not find intent to settings of Play store but it is showing others apps intent. Could you please post the intent of settings of play store if possible?

Comment: Well, there is probably no public Intent avaiable to this Activity, I'm afraid.